# How can I get the screen width and height using appJar?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, screen-size

Is there a way to use `appJar` itself to get the screen height and width.

Alternativley since `appJar` is a wrapper for `tkinter` is there a way for me to create a `Tk()` instance to utilise the below code I have seen used everywhere whilst research:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

I would like to do this so I can use these sizes for setting window sizes later with the `.setGeometry()` method, e.g.

```
# Fullscreen
app.setGeometry(width, height)
```

or:

```
# Horizontal halfscreen
app.setGeometry(int(width / 2), height)
```

or:

```
# Vertical halfscren
app.setGeometry(width, int(height / 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `appJar` is just a wrapper over `tkinter`, you need a reference to `root`/`master` instance of `Tk()`, which stored as `self.topLevel` in `gui`.
Alternatively, you can take a reference to a prettier `self.appWindow`, which is "child" canvas of `self.topLevel`.

To make all things clear - just add some "shortcuts" to desired methods of an inherited class!

```
import appJar as aJ

class App(aJ.gui):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        aJ.gui.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def winfo_screenheight(self):
        #   shortcut to height
        #   alternatively return self.topLevel.winfo_screenheight() since topLevel is Tk (root) instance!
        return self.appWindow.winfo_screenheight()

    def winfo_screenwidth(self):
        #   shortcut to width
        #   alternatively return self.topLevel.winfo_screenwidth() since topLevel is Tk (root) instance!
        return self.appWindow.winfo_screenwidth()


app = App('winfo')
height, width = app.winfo_screenheight(), app.winfo_screenwidth()
app.setGeometry(int(width / 2), int(height / 2))
app.addLabel('winfo_height', 'height: %d' % height, 0, 0)
app.addLabel('winfo_width', 'width: %d' % width, 1, 0)
app.go()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, `appJar` does allow you to create `Tk()` instance. So I was able to create an instance using the functions to retrieve the dimensions and destroy the then unneeded instance.

```
# import appjar
from appJar import appjar

# Create an app instance to get the screen dimensions
root = appjar.Tk()

# Save the screen dimensions
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# Destroy the app instance after retrieving the screen dimensions
root.destroy()
```